# Java split string at custom position

Tags: java, string, split

I have large String something like:

```
String = "ABC114.553111.325785.658EFG114.256114.589115.898";
```

I would like to achieve:

```
String1 = "ABC";
String2 = "114.553";
String3 = "111.325";
String4 = "785.658";
```

Sometimes it isn't three digits then dot and four digits after. But always Before digits there is three letters.

Comment: Can you describe the pattern? What you have shown so far and what you have said doesn't seem to follow a pattern.

Comment: Is that possible to insert some characters into the String you want to split?

Comment: "Sometimes it isn't three digits then dot and four digits after" - How would you differentiate this: `114.5533 & 111.3257` from this: `114.553 & 3111.3257` given the input: `114.5533111.3257`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following  regexp:

```
([^\.]){3}(\....)?
```

Here a program...

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class C {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "([^\\.]){3}(\\....)?";
        String b = "ABC114.553111.325785.658EFG114.256114.589115.898";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(a);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(b);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("found: " + matcher.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
found: ABC
found: 114.553
found: 111.325
found: 785.658
found: EFG
found: 114.256
found: 114.589
found: 115.898
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String s = "ABC114.553111.325785.658EFG114.256114.589115.898";
Matcher prefixes = Pattern.compile("([A-Z]{3})").matcher(s);
for (String part : s.split("[A-Z]{3}")) {
    if (part.equals("")) {
        continue;
    }

    prefixes.find();
    System.out.println(prefixes.group(0));

    for (int i = 0; i < part.length(); i += 7) {
        System.out.println(part.substring(i, i + 7));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
ABC
114.553
111.325
785.658
EFG
114.256
114.589
115.898
```

Comment: Only thing you missed is OP specified the letters as part of the output

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I updated the example accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A bad option can be to loop over string 0 to n-4. and keep track of (i+3)th character, if it is ".", you know where to split - at "i".

@Matt  - You lost strings of alphabets "ABC" and "EFG", those were supposed to be retained.